# Any way to bake with Eevee?

Tags: baking

Cycles is tricky to bake, unecessary realism and I have better overall control of my scene with Eevee. Is there any add-on for it or is Blender ever gonna get it?

Comment: If you mean texture baking, currently its not possible with eevee

Answer (score 3):

Baking in eevee is currently **not possible**
You can bake indirect lighting, but not textures. For further reading, I found [this](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/X0dbbc/) pretty interesting community post.

It may eventually get implemented one day.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if relevant, but I got a decent baking of two "eevee" material with "shader to rgb" node inside just baking IN CYCLE the emit component not the diffuse one. The materials are not identical but just very similar.
You may want to see the node of the material here [image]and the result here https://skfb.ly/o8sQV.